# where can I get OpenCL multigpu sample code?

Tags: c, opencl, multi-gpu

I am studying about the OpenCl. So I just testing about the vector addition by using multiple GPU.
When a problem of the same size was copied and executed by increasing the number of queues by the number of devices, the time increased by the number of devices.
I'm guessing this is because I use a blocking api.
so I want to see some sample about the how to use multi gpu in OpenCL.

My codes are below..

```
// Setup kernel arguments
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_A);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_B);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_C);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(int), &M);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(int), &N);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(int), &K);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);

err = clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_A);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_B);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_C);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 3, sizeof(int), &M);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 4, sizeof(int), &N);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 5, sizeof(int), &K);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);

err = clSetKernelArg(kernel3, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_A);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel3, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_B);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel3, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &gpu_mem_C);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel3, 3, sizeof(int), &M);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel3, 4, sizeof(int), &N);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel3, 5, sizeof(int), &K);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);

// Run kernel
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, gws, lws, 0, NULL, NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel2, 2, NULL, gws, lws, 0, NULL, NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue,kernel3, 2, NULL, gws,lws,0,NULL,NULL);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
err = clFinish(queue);
CHECK_OPENCL(err);
```

Comment: The easiest solution here is just to use multiple threads. Most OpenCL calls are thread safe, so if you manage one device/queue/kernel on each thread, you should be able to improve performance.

Comment: @apetranzilla you rarely need to use multiple threads to access opencl command queues. opencl command queues are thread safe (and usually create a runtime thread behind the scene). As long a you don't perform any blocking calls, you can efficiently schedule commands via a single host thread.

Comment: @EladMaimoni that is true, but it's usually easier to write the logic using multiple threads and blocking calls, since you can write everything as regular sequential code. Either approach would work, I would just start with separate threads because it's easier than interleaving the logic into one thread.